# How SwiftUI detects there are @State variable values passed to subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Below is a simple example which doesn't use `@Binding`, but pass `@State` variable value directly to subviews (through closure).

```
 1  import SwiftUI
   
 2  struct ContentView: View {
 3      @State var counter = 0
 4      var body: some View {
 5          print("ContentView")
 6          return VStack {
 7              Button("Tap me!") { self.counter += 1 }
 8              LabelView(number: counter)
 9          }
10      }
11  }
   
12  struct LabelView: View {
13      let number: Int
14      var body: some View {
15          print("LabelView")
16          return Group {
17                  Text("You've tapped \(number) times")
18          }
19      }
20  }
```

Tapping the button modifies `@State` variable, which then causes both`ContentView` and `LabelView` get updated. A common explanation is that, because the toplevel view's `@State` variable changes, so the toplevel ivew's body is re-executed.

But my experiments show that it's not that simple.

- For example, if I remove the `LabelView(number: counter)` call (see line 8 above) in the code, then tapping the button won't get ContentView.body() executed.
- For another example, if I pass `@Binding` variable, instead of `@State` variable value to subview, then tapping the button won't get ContentView.body() executed either.

**So it seems that SwiftUI knows that if toplevel view's `@State` variable value is passed to subviews. I wonder how it determines that?** I know compiler has this kind of information. But SwiftUI is a framework written in Swift. I don't think Swift has this kind of feature.

While writing this question, I realize one possible way to do it. Note the above code is executed when creating initial view hierarchy. That is, if a `@State` variable is passed to a subview, its getter must get executed *before* view update. It seems SwiftUI might take advantage of this to determine if there are `@State` variables is passed to a subview (or accessed in toplevel view's body).

Is that the way how it works? I wonder how you guys understand it? Thanks.

---

**Update 1**:

Below is my summary of the discussion with @Shadowrun, who helped to put the pieces together. I don't know if it's really what happens under the hood, but it seems reasonable to me. I write it down in case it helps others too.

1. SwiftUI runtime maintains view hiearchy somehow. For example,

   - For subviews, this may be done with the help of viewbuilders. For example, viewbuilders registers subviews with the runtime.
   - For toplevel view, this may be done by runtime (note toplevel view's body is a regular computed property and not transformed by viewbuilder).
2. SwiftUI can detect if state variable is read or written through its getter/setter.
3. This is hypothesis. When SwiftUI creates the initial view hiearchy, it does the following for each view:

   - Set current view
   - Run the view's body code (I find that body of layout types like VStack has `Never` type. I suppose it has an equivalent way to iterate through its subviews).
   - If SwiftUI detects that the view's state variable is read, it save the dependency between that state variable and the view somewhere. So if the app modifies that state variable later, the view's body will be executed to update the view.

     - Scenario 1: If the view body doesn't read the view's state variable, it won't trigger the above mechanism. As a result, the view won't be updated when the app modifies the state variable.
     - Scenario 2: If the view pass its state variable to its subview through binding (that is, the state variable's projectedvalue), it won't trigger the above mechanism either, because reading/writing a state variable's projectedvalue is through Binding property wrapper's getter/setter, not State property wrapper's getter/setter.

---

**Update 2**：

An interesting detail. Note the `+=` operator in line 7. It's usually implemented as reading and writing. So the button handler in line 7 read state variable also. However, button handler isn't called when creating initial view hierarchy, so based on the theory above SwiftUI won't recall `ContentView.body` just because of line 7. This can be proved by removing line 8.

**Update 3**：

I have a new and much simpler explanation to the original question. In my original question I asekd:

> So it seems that SwiftUI knows that if toplevel view's @State variable value is passed to subviews. I wonder how it determines that?

It's a wrong question. It's very likely that SwiftUI doesn't really knows that the state is passed to subview. Instead it just knows that the state is accessed in the view's body(perhaps using a similar mechanism I described above). So, if a view's state changes, it reevaluates the view's body. Just this simple rule.

Comment: I understand it this way: when you call the ctor `LabelView(number: counter)` in `body` of ContentView - LabelView will be drawn - just because it is part of the ContentView. `body` will be called whenever the state changes. While there is actually a lot of "magic" in SwiftUI, in this case I think there is none :)

Comment: Hi @CouchDeveloper, your explanation is the "common explanation" I mentioned in my question. But it's not really that simple. Please see the two examples I gave in my question where `ContentView.body` is not executed even though state variable changes.

Comment: When you remove `LabelView(number: counter) `, it seems when _not_ referencing `counter`, property wrapper `@State` will not create subscriptions under the hood, and thus `body` will not be called. Somewhere in WWDC  [Introducing Swift UI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204/) it is stated that _"One of the special properties of `@State` variables is that SwiftUI can observe when they're read and written."_. This supports the above assumption. Going to the source code would reveal the magic. (what happens if you just add `print(counter)`?)

Comment: Adding `print(counter)` causes `ContentView.body` executed (of course). So you think `@State` is implementing based on combine? If so, the subscription needs to be set up ahead, and hence it should be possible to get the dependency between state varibles and subviews. However, I doubt if `@State` is really implemented using combine. I don't see there is any need for that, because swiftui can easily observe state variables' read and write through State property wrapper's getter and setter.

Comment: SwiftUI is based on Combine. The "magic" happens in the property wrappers. There's actually quite lot of code involved in that seemingly simple statement that references `counter`. Unfortunately, Apple's Swift UI is not open source, but there is an attempt to reimplement exactly this peace of mechanic for the purpose of figuring out how this _might_ work: https://gist.github.com/AliSoftware/ecb5dfeaa7884fc0ce96178dfdd326f8

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've taken a quick look at it and need more time to digest it. I think the article proves what I said - there is no need to use Combine to implement `State` and `Binding` property wrapper. I also read often that SwiftUI is based on Combine. I guess that is probably about other things (e.g. SwiftUI is often used with MMVC and hence Combine, etc.)

Comment: Well, yes looking closer - you may be right: `@State` and `@Binding` can be actually simple and do not need to use Combine. Could even be main-thread confined and everything could be synchronous. Too bad, we cannot see the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the state property wrapper SwiftUI can know when a variable is read, because it can manage access via custom getter function.
When a view builder closure is being evaluated, SwiftUI knows which builder function it’s evaluating and can set its state such that any state variables read during that evaluation are then known to be dependencies of the view currently being evaluated.

At runtime: the flow might look like this:

```
Need to render ContentView, so:
  set currentView = ContentView
  call each function in the function builder...
  ...LabelView(number: counter) - this calls the getter for counter

Getter for counter is:
  associate <currentView> with counter (means any time counter changes, need to recompute <currentView>)
  return value of counter


...after ContentView function builder
 Current view = nil
```

But with a stack of current views...

Comment: Hi @Shadowrun IIUIC, you meant view builder establishes the dependency between state variables and view's body closures. In my example code, line 8 is the only place where the state variable is associated with LabelView. So the dependency has to be created in BuildExpression(), right? But from this doc (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md), buildExpression() can only transform an expression's return value. It can't really parse an expression. So how does it know the func's parameter is state variable?

Comment: Not quite, not the view builder on its own. The SwiftUI runtime knows it's about to recompute a view by calling its body function. Before it calls that body function it sets state to say watch out for any @state getter functions called starting now, (and when function returns, stop watching state getters to associate view V with state vars called) that's how I think of it anyway

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure what you mean. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update above. I think we all agree that it's State property wrapper's getter does the trick. But I suspect the details in your flow is not correct. According to your pseudo code, when ContentView's state variable chagnes, its body function should get executed. It's not true. You can run my above example code. Tap the button (note this changes state). And you wil see that only "LabelView" was printed on the console. That means when state changes, ContentView.body() isn't re-executed.

Comment: It seems that when view builder processes line 8, the currentview in your code should be VStack. In that way, your theory works :) That said, I'm afraid I can't accept your answer yet until I'm quite confident in it. Thanks.

Comment: When I run it (on MacOS) I see "LabelView ContentView LabelView ContentView" etc and the label says "You've tapped 9 times" - this is as we should expect, I think?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The result is exactly like what you observed. But I have a question about the `set currentView = ContentView` line in your pseudo code. It's impossible for view builder to do that because view builder can only transform line 6-9. Line 4-10 is the body of computed property. It's not processed by view builder. So, it seems it's unlikely for view builder to be able to associate `ContentView.body` with any state variables at all. (It's late here. I'll get offline and check message tomorrow.)

Comment: Think about the SwiftUI runtime. That's the piece of software that under the hood is manipulating the actual UIViews. It's that runtime that I say is doing the set currentView = ContentView before it calls the functions (each line) in the function builder (the body) to figure out what to do, what has changed, and what depends on what.

Comment: I added a summary of the discussion to my question and accepted your answer. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT AN ANSWER**

I’m a web guy, not familiar with swift, but came across this post and find it interesting. I’m curious to see how would this piece of code behave? Think this would test your theory:

```swift
import SwiftUI
   
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var counter1 = 0
    @State var counter2 = 0
    var body: some View {
        print("ContentView")
        if Bool.random() {
            return VStack {
                Button("Tap me!") { self.counter2 += 1 }
                LabelView(number: counter1)
            }
        } else {
            return VStack {
                Button("Tap me!") { self.counter1 += 1 }
                LabelView(number: counter2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

To answer your question:

> Do you know if ReactJS has similar concepts or objects like @State, @Binding, @Environment, etc?

To be clear, there's no implicit getter/setter tracking in ReactJS that automatically triggers a view update (aka re-render). The sole API to trigger a re-render is an explicit call to `setState()` function.

However there're features comparable to SwiftUI's `@State` and `@Binding` in React. In short, `@State` corresponds to `this.state` and `@Binding` corresponds to `this.props`.

A typical React "class component" looks like this:

```js
class CounterView extends React.Component {
  // `constructor` is equiv to `init` in swift
  constructor(props) {
    // this calls the constructor of base class `React.Component`
    // which would assign `this.props = props`
    // where as `props` is a struct passed-in from outside, most likely from parent component.
    super(props)

    // `this` keyword is equiv to `self` in swift
    // in SwiftUI you declare `@State counter` property right on the instance
    // in React you need to put `counter` property inside a nested `this.state` struct
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, [
      // in SwiftUI you need to declare `@Binding heading`
      // in React, because JS is dynamic lang,
      // you can simply access any properties of the passed-in `this.props` struct
      React.createElement("h1", null, this.props.heading),
      React.createElement("button", {
        // you modify local state by calling `setState` API
        onClick: () => this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
      }, "Tap me!"),
      React.createElement("span", null, this.state.counter)
    ])
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, the above example code certainly shows you know more about SwiftUI than me (I know Swift, but I have just started learning SwiftUI :) Seriously, that's very clever test. IIUIC, the key design is that initial view creation and later view update have different code path. The test result is, when tapping button, there is no output. I think it proves the hypothesis in my update. What happens is: 1) Let's assume Bool.random() returns True, counter1's getter is called and a dependency on it is added. 2) However, tapping the button update counter2, and hence `ContentView.body` isn't executed.

Comment: BTW, since you are doing web programming. I have a question. SwiftUI is similar to ReactJS in that both uses virtual DOM (it's virtual view hiearchy, instead of virtual DOM, in SwiftUI, but the concept is similar). Do you know if ReactJS has similar concepts or objects like `@State`, `@Binding`, `@Environment`, etc?

Comment: And just FYI, there are a few open source projects aiming to provide SwiftUI compatible API for web programming, like https://github.com/SwiftWebUI/SwiftWebUI and https://github.com/TokamakUI/Tokamak. So if you are curious, you may want to check out their source code to see how they implement view update dependency. I plan to do it later this year.

Comment: Good to know! In React, the sole API to trigger a re-render is an explicit call to `setState(newValue)` function, and that call will compare the newValue against oldValue to see if any update is necessary. So there isn't any getter/setter tracking.

Comment: However, this tracking technique is used in other framework. Like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) use the same idea like SwiftUI. And [svelte](https://svelte.dev/) does approximately the same but with compile time analysis, not tracking in runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the information. And just in case it's not clear in the discussion, my question in the post is not about implicit or explicit call, but about how SwiftUI determines which subview needs to be update or which not. It's about optimization.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what the discussion is about. And I just added a sample code to address your question about React, to give you a taste. I've briefly tried out SwiftUI before, it resembles React in many ways.

Comment: Thanks! I see your point - in ReactJS each component sets a dirty flag by explicitly calling setState(). This is like what the State property wrapper setter does. But ReactJS probably doesn't have a counterpart to State property wrapper getter.

Comment: And because of that, even if `counter` is not used at all, a re-render cycle is still triggered, `render()` function is re-executed (which is not optimal), but there's no real negative effect because when the engine diffs the two virtual DOM tree, they look identical, thus no real view update is applied.